# Static IP Addresses and OpenStack

Tags: ip, openstack

I'm working within an environment where static IP addresses are the prescribed method. I have a set of IP addresses [about 10] and I'm trying to get that to be the pool of IPs that OpenStack can use. Is there anyway to get openstack to only choose from the set?

More information- I got a range of IP addresses of 172.10.42.172-180 so its not something you can slice out very easy with a submask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this only works with Nova networking, not with Quantum)

You can add the IPs one by one:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 172 180`
do
    nova-manage floating create --ip_range=172.10.42.$i
done
```

Then you can allocate each of them to your project either using `nova create-floating-ip` or the "Allocate IP to Project" in Horizon Dashboard.